# Javascript dropdown - creating links and text

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if anyone could help me out complete some functionality for a dropdown I am trying to make.

The current portlet is on a test page located at http://www.khl.com/dev/american-cranes-and-transport/ there is  section on the right called "Dealer Locator" this is the problematic code.

Currently the Dealer locater is working fine although I am trying to add extra functionality.

- When someone selects a company from the dropdown I would like the image to have a link
- When someone selects a company from the dropdown I would like the Related text to change to desired text.

Attached is the code which is used on that page (if someone has dreamweaver or something similar I would really appreciate if you could put it in there)

Anyway this is a long shot but any solution would be appreciated.

```
<img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif" width="300"  border="0" usemap="#Map" longdesc="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif">
<map name="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="8,11,127,88" href="http://www.scranet.org/" target="_blank" alt="SC&amp;RA">
</map>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
// if you preload images they need to be loaded before they are required 
// once in the cash they can be used as the original file name(&path) or as new Image.src ie SRC[1].src 

ImgPath='http://www.vicsjavascripts.org.uk/StdImages/'; 
ImgPreloadAry=new Array('One.gif','Two.gif','Three.gif','Four.gif'); 
SRCAry=new Array(); 

for (i=0;i<ImgPreloadAry.length;i++){ 
 SRCAry[i]=new Image(); 
 SRCAry[i].src=ImgPath+ImgPreloadAry[i]; 
} 

function Cng(sel){ 
 document.getElementById('img').src=ImgPath+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
 document.getElementById('tbl').style.backgroundImage='url('+(ImgPath+sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value)+')'; 
} 





//--> 
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="149"><img src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif" alt="" width="130" height="80" id=img></td>
        <td width="151">Related text goes here - along with link to pdf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
<table width="149" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="149" align="left" valign="top">
            <select name="Sel" size="1" onchange="Cng(this);" >
                <option value="One.gif">Company 1</option>
                <option value="Two.gif">Company 2</option>
                <option value="Three.gif">Company 3</option>
                <option value="Four.gif">Company 4</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the image inside an anchor first and the on each dropdownchange you can change the href attribute of the anchor. Like -

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
       <td width="149">
          <a id="companyLink" href="#">
             <img id="relatedImage" src="http://www.khl.com/other_files/khl/dealer-locatot.gif" alt="" width="130" height="80" id=img>
          </a>
       </td>
       <td id="relatedText" width="151">Related text goes here - along with link to pdf</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And in javascript you have define an array which will contain objects with ImageLink and the Text you want to display as properties. Like -

```
var ImgPath='http://www.vicsjavascripts.org.uk/StdImages/';
var linksArray = [
  { Img: 'One.gif', Link : 'http://www.companyone.com', RelatedText :'Description for company one'},
  {Img:'Two.gif', Link : 'http://www.companytwo.com', RelatedText :'Description for company two'},
  {Img:'Three.gif', Link : 'http://www.companythree.com',RelatedText : 'Description for company three'},
  {Img:'Four.gif', Link : 'http://www.companyfour.com',RelatedText : 'Description for company four'},
];

function Cng(sel){ 
   var selectedIndex = sel.selectedIndex;
   document.getElementById('companyLink').href = linksArray[selectedIndex].Link;
   document.getElementById('relatedText').innerHTML= linksArray[selectedIndex].RelatedText;
   document.getElementById('relatedImage').src = ImgPath + linksArray[selectedIndex].Img;
}
```

I hope this is what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reponse although I am struggling to get it working. Could you add it into the code I provided as I am struggling to get the RelatedText appearing on selection.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Actually there was a typo in  document.getElementById('relatedText').innerHTML. I have corrected it and I think this would solve the problem.